# How to debug SSIS package in SQL Server Management Studio 2017?

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-2017

How to debug SSIS package in SQL Server Management Studio 2017?

Comment: You can't you will need SSDT/Visual Studio to debug SSIS packages. SSMS is not the development tool for SSIS Packages.

Comment: So there is no way in SSMS for debugging the SSIS package? I already  know how to debug SSIS packages in SSDT/Visual Studio and looking for the same in SSMS. Thanks.

Comment: nope, this is what exactly I said in my last comment

Comment: You can use the SSIS catalog API. For example data taps. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2846/data-tapping-during-ssis-package-execution-in-sql-server-2012/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSMS, after a package executes you can right-click it and choose `Reports>All Executions` and see an execution history of that report.  Each of the three available sub-reports contains information about that execution that can be useful in debugging.

That's about all you can do in SSMS.